# Using do-file with local macro

Tags: global-variables, stata, local-variables, stata-macros

I am getting the following error in Stata while using a `do` file with a local macro:

```
clear 
capture log close

sysuse auto,clear 
log using stata,text replace

local varlist  price mpg rep78 weight length
reg 'varlist'
local close
```

Output

```
local varlist  price mpg rep78 weight length

reg 'varlist'
invalid name
```

I know that this is a very trivial issue, but I am not sure where this error is coming from.

Note that I didn't get error when I used global macro.

Comment: It seems you have the wrong title. This isn't an R, Knitr, or Lyx question, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To deregister a local macro the left quote should be a backtick. Try the following.

```
regress `varlist'
```

The backtick is on the same key as the tilde (i.e., ~) on most keyboards.

Comment: "most keyboards" may be true; it is most likely to be true for keyboards sold in the USA.